# How to handle duplicate .module files that live in 2 places?

Tags: 7, files

I have not used Drupal before and have been thrown a project to fix up some things.

But I noticed the file I need to edit lives in two places:

- one in `includes/jobs.module`.
- another one in `sites/all/modules/jobs/jobs.module`.

Is one meant to be a sym link of the other or something? As this is not the case in the project I have been given. What file should I be editing?

I'm sure this is basic stuff for and Drupal dev. An suggetions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There shouldn't be a job.module in the includes directory at all, your module files for your job module should all be in sites/all/modules/jobs.

You generally shouldn't put anything in (or modify anything in) the includes directory or you will make it harder for yourself to upgrade drupal core in future.

I would say you should:

1. check for any differences between the two files.
2. If they are different determine whether or not anything in includes/jobs.module should be in sites/all/modules/jobs/jobs.module. If so add it.
3. Delete includes/jobs.module

Answer (score 3):

To further completed the answer from Rooby, you may want to consider using the [Hacked](https://www.drupal.org/project/hacked) module, which will identify various similar issues that may exist in your Drupal sites. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... scans the currently installed Drupal, contributed modules and themes, re-downloads them and determines if they have been changed. Changes are marked clearly and if the diff module is installed then Hacked! will allow you to see the exact lines that have changed.